# How can I launch the Unity Editor and open a specific project from C# code?

Tags: unity, c#

I created a very simple console application:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The project I want to open
            var arg = @"""-projectPath C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\New Unity Project""";

            // Start Unity and open the project
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe", arg);
        }
    }
}
```

But only the Unity Editor is launched; the specified project is not opened.

What do I need to modify to launch the project?

Comment: I've tried with and without the extra quotation marks but nothing happened.

Comment: Since the path to the project contains spaces, I would surround it with quotes.

Comment: did you mean to write `@"\"-projectPath C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\New Unity Project\""` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a better question for the [SuperUser StackExchange](https://superuser.com/), as your problem isn't specific to game development, it's just about formatting your command line arguments correctly.

When you write arg like this:

```
var arg = @"""-projectPath C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\New Unity Project""";
```

That's equivalent to typing this into your command line:

```
Unity.exe "-projectPath C:\Users\..." (etc)
```

As Hellium points out in the comments above, you want the quotation marks around the *path*, not the whole command line argument string. Like this:

```
var arg = @"-projectPath ""C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\New Unity Project""";
```

Then in the command line it looks like this:

```
Unity.exe -projectPath "C:\Users\..." (etc)
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of posting on StackOverflow. Thank you for your help. This solved my problem.